# How to use custom Ruby on Rails Engine helpers inside the Main App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, rails-engines

I have created a custom Rails engine that I am using on my main app. In my Rails engine I used some methods in application_helper along with other resource specific helpers. My question is, how to invoke these methods while mounting the engine on main app?